# What is causing desktop shield icon overlay on *SOME* desktops

Tags: windows, delphi, manifest, c++builder, uac

I have a C++ Builder/Delphi application. It has the following manifest embedded as a resource:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                    processorArchitecture="*"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
                    name="Manufacturer.Division.MyName" />
  <description>MyName</description>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                        version="6.0.0.0"
                        processorArchitecture="*"
                        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
                        language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" /> <!-- Win Vista and Win Serv 2008    -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" /> <!-- Win 7     and Win Serv 2008 R2 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" /> <!-- Win 8     and Win Serv 2012    -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" /> <!-- Win 8.1   and Win Serv 2012 R2 -->
    </application>
  </compatibility>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

The software does not utilize registry HKLM - only HKCU, and it reads/writes to %LocalAppData%. It does not require administrative privileges.

The **requestedExecutionLevel** is set to **asInvoker** as seen from above XML manifest so it should not show shield icon.

On some desktops the shield icon does not appear and on some it does - other programs do not show shield icon on the same desktop. What is possibly causing shield icon (and the annoying UAC prompt) for my application?

On all systems - the user type is Administrator and UAC is set to default level (on Windows 7 and 8) - so I really see no cause of shield to be shown only on some and not on all desktops.

What is different on these systems where the shield icon appears compared to the ones where shield icon is not present?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5778463/632951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executable file has compatibility options set to force the application to execute as administrator.

[image]

Comment: This is a possibility (I will test it), but so far, I added this on my own system (where shield icon does not appear) and it did not add shield icon (even though the prompt appears because program shortcut is set to request administrative privileges). Are there any other possibilities causing this? Or can compatibility options be set somewhere else except "Properties" on the program icon?

Comment: You are being confused by the icon cache. I suspect a restart will force the icon to be updated. You can also check this option on an executable, and then create a shortcut. Then you'll see the shield. Assuming that the shortcut you create doesn't already have a cached icon. I am >99% sure that this is the cause of what you observe.

Comment: Thank you - mystery solved! It was indeed that checkbox - just checked on one of the affected desktops!

Comment: Shield icon also appears sometimes for executable files downloaded from internet.

Comment: @SilverWarior I don't think so. The fact it came from the internet won't result in UAC elevation.

Comment: You might also want to ensure where the exe is getting installed, and if that's really the proper location.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, How can the cache be refreshed without a restart? It doesn't seem to update the icon on my side regardless of whether the checkbox is ticked or not.

Comment: @pace easiest way is to restart