# My application icon is receiving the "administrator shield"

Tags: delphi, uac

My Win32 Delphi application icon is receiving the "administrator shield" on a specific Windows 7 computer despite the fact that:

- I'm not using the application manifest that requires administrator access
- the application name doesn't include any words like "setup", "install", or "update"
- the application doesn't have "run as administrator" selected in the shortcut properties for the user, "all users", or in the advanced properties.

Fortunately, this is a very rare situation.  It, however, is experienced by a customer who is very far away.

this came to my attention because the runtime library TPath.GetTempFileName method is raising an exception "The directory name is invalid".  when running a test application (not as administrator), the temp path is available and R/W access is available.  don't know what happens if the test application is run as administrator.

I have mused that maybe it was installed by the administrator or that the UAC settings on that computer are very strict in some way.

It is an older version of my application but I don't like the fact that it is not understood what the problem is.

Being an old version of the application, I'm not inclined to dig deeply to solve this; in a way, it *has* been solved but I'd like to understand why.

Only looking for quick answers here--not an in-depth community effort.

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing desktop shield icon overlay on \*SOME\* desktops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391978/what-is-causing-desktop-shield-icon-overlay-on-some-desktops)

Comment: I'd answer, but you are only looking for a quick answer, and my answer is more in depth. So I won't.

Comment: @JerryDodge -- thank you for your comment.  that was the first thing I checked and none of the checkboxes for that are selected.

Comment: Did you also read the comments on that other answer? Either way, you both have exactly the same question. If the other answer doesn't solve your problem, you can start a bounty on the other question and add additional details to the question.

Comment: When a UAC manifest is NOT present in a 32bit app, Installer Detection takes effect, which uses different heuristics to guess whether the app might be an installer: keywords in the filename, keywords in version resources, keywords in a side-by-side manifest, keywords in specific StringTable resources, key attributes in RC data linked in the app, and even specific byte sequences within the app. If you simply add a UAC manifest, like you should be, all of that guesswork goes away.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I had read the answer and the comments.  The application icon didn't have any "run as administrator" checkboxes selected.  Ever.  I saw pictures showing this.  Therefore, I concluded it can't be an icon caching problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  didn't know that; thank you for pointing that out!  the manifest is the one offered by delphi if you select to use XP themes.  It includes a requestedPrivileges section and an execution level of asInvoker.  All this is done in a traditional way.

Comment: IIRC, the name of the EXE could also trigger it.

Comment: @Graymatter: that falls into the "keywords in the filename" portion of my earlier comment. But Installer Detection (which is what performs the filename check) only applies when "requestedExecutionLevel` is not present.

Comment: @X-Ray: if there is a manifest that includes `requestedExecutionLevel`, regardless of its value, then Installer Detection does not apply at all. So something else outside of the app would have to be triggering the shield icon. And BTW, since when did Delphi start including `requestedExecutionLevel` in its default manifest? I have never seen it do that. Must be something new they added in recent versions.

Comment: @Graymatter    Yes, setup, update, and install for instance.  I am not using anything that would trigger this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  certainly XE3 does.  looked at a project I just started a couple of days ago to confirm & it had requestedExecutionLevel...   I assumed it was some kind of IT department configuration issue.

Comment: @X-Ray: I just checked the default manifest in XE and XE2 and they both have a default `requestedExecutionLevel` as well. I never noticed that before. Good to know. I must have been thinking about the old XPMan component's default manifest before theming was natively added to the VCL. That manifest did not have `requestedExecutionLevel`.